# Ubuntu 16.04 - fsck running - prevent login

Tags: 16.04, login-screen, fsck

Is it normal that Ubuntu prevents me to login when it's running fsck?

When I input my user and password it shows me this message:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 281922/7077888 files, 6496532/28293888
```

Then come back to login screen.

[image: Look this gif]

**UPDATE**

I've just remenbered that I've changed AMD video community driver by proprietary driver, maybe is it the problem?!

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing. This is normal. It's not preventing login. It's just a message displayed before the login screen is ready.

Comment: But I input user and password, press enter, screen goes black, showing fsck message, then go back to login screen, I can't use the system.

Comment: You have a login loop. It has nothing to do with the message. There are lots of different causes of this. Often, going to ctrl-alt-f1, logging in there, and doing rm .Xauthority is enough. Or there could be a different cause in your case.  Another common cause is having the wrong video driver. Search through the site on login loop.

Comment: Well, thanks. Só, is there a way to remove video driver from command line? I'll search it, but if you know, please, tell me.

Comment: I really don't know offhand. If I had known I certainly would have told you or answered the question. :) But there are many similar questions. I'm sure you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fglrx because it's not supported on Ubuntu 16.04.
To solve the problem I removed fglrx.

```
apt-get remove --purge fglrx fgrlx_* fglrx-dev*
```