# Ubuntu stuck on boot, won't get past fsck!

Tags: boot, 16.04, mouse, fsck

This is the second time this has happened. I have disabled mouse acceleration on Ubuntu by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698961/disable-mouse-acceleration-in-ubuntu-15-10).

Immediately after that I tried to log out but the system got hung at the fsck screen, so after about 5 mins I force-shutdown the system and when turning it on again Ubuntu got stuck on the fsck screen and won't get past that!

I have tried using a live USB to both delete the file that I created and also run fsck on the sda6 partition and it says everything is OK. Don't really know what to do now. This is what it looks like:

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: Follow the instructions for using `nomodeset` at http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it and then make sure that you have the correct/newest video drivers installed.

Comment: @heynnema I'm sorry. I don't know if I didn't understand that or if I didn't explain well. The live USB does boot no problem, but the ubuntu installed on my hard drive isn't booting. By running ubuntu from a liveUSB I am able to delete the file that I created before the installed Ubuntu stopped working, and also perform fsck on the sda6 partition where ubuntu is installed. I have Intel HD graphics (first i3 gen) and the drivers were up to date. I didn't have a problem until I disabled mouse acceleration by creating that file.

Comment: Do you remember the name and location of that file that you created? Remember the contents of the file? I doubt that it caused your problem. Can you boot your normal hard disk into recovery mode successfully?

Comment: At the GRUB menu, hit the "e" key. This will take you into edit mode. Find the line that has "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset". Then hit control-x to boot with the temporary mod in place. See if that boots.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, the file I created was a file to disable mouse acceleration. Using a live USB I deleted that file but the system still didn't boot. I'm gonna try to nomodset option now and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I tried nomodeset and the loading screen looked stretched, so I guess it did take effect. However the system still won't boot, it got stuck at the last loading circle below the logo.

Comment: I'm out of quick ideas. Visit the web site link that I gave you earlier for more troubleshooting tips... http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Actually... one more idea... edit the GRUB thing and change "quite splash" to "nomodeset" then control-x to boot. You should see a screenfull of text as it boots... the LAST few lines should tell you how/where it's failing.

Comment: Doing that resulted in a blank screen, with no printed information. I think I'm just gonna back up and reinstall ubuntu again. I hope this doesn't happen a third time.

Comment: Edit the GRUB parameters and remove "quiet" if that got added. It may be that the fsck is not where the system is hanging.

Answer (score 6):

After experiencing this exact same issue, using Ubuntu 16.04.02, I found a couple of ways to work around it. It seemed my problems were caused by changing the graphics nvidia drivers, and although I haven't found a way to properly work the drivers, I can get the regular login operation working again.

1. First Fix.

   - I used <kbd>ESC</kbd> on the startup ubuntu purple splash to be able to enter `GRUB`.
   - Using <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the grub `ubuntu` boot command, I added the command **`nomodeset`** to the line starting with `linux`, just before other commands `quiet splash`. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) for an example.
   - At the Ubuntu Login Screen, I got caught into a login loop, where the same startup process was obviously being called. To get past this, using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> you can login and enter a terminal.
   - Use `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` to remove the unusable graphics drivers. Can be installed again later if need be. (ie, [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/))
2. Second Fix (Context: After achieving sucess with the first method, I proceeded to reinstall nvidia drivers to attempt to get the working again. Doing so, I also restarted `xserver` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) which ended up breaking my login process, and even with `nomodeset` still resulted in the same issue.) Looks like the GIF in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769508/ubuntu-16-04-fsck-running-prevent-login).

   - To get past this block, I needed to boot into a **recovery mode** configuration of Ubuntu.
   - Use <kbd>ESC</kbd> on the startup ubuntu purple splash to be able to enter `GRUB`. Select `Advanced options for Ubuntu`.
   - Selected `Root` option to drop to a root shell prompt.
   - Use `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` to remove the unusable graphics drivers.
   - Use [Method 2](https://askubuntu.com/a/21310/210504) to reset `xserver` dependencies. This is because xserver hosts nouveau drivers for graphics cards.

You should now have regular access to your Ubuntu instillation, but I can't comment on your graphics card functionality.

Comment: Oh, man.. I don't have that computer anymore, so I can't test this. That one had Intel graphics though. I hope this is useful for someone else in the future. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I'm still dealing with, as I just found with an Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade.  It seems nVidia and Ubuntu (and Linus, and Wayland, and...) [aren't really getting along](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15564611) at the moment, leaving us all to suffer.  [nVidia driver bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1752053) are causing a lot of problems.

I had to:

- boot after upgrade, into the same screen posted in the question
- google google google on my phone
- ctrl-alt-F2 to open a tty
- sudo apt purge nvidia*
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
- sudo apt update
- work out which damned chipset i had against available drivers (ok i just picked most recent)
- sudo apt install nvidia-390
- sudo apt upgrade # which fixed a bunch of dependencies
- boot, edit boot line to add nomodeset (and there's that nasty noveau driver...rrrr...)
- And that didn't work... so I reinstalled gnome and gdm3 via: sudo apt install --reinstall gnome gdm3
- And that got me crawling into a GNOME desktop
- From there, I found X startup errors when running i3; I removed the previous manual /etc/X11/xorg.conf that was pointing at nvidia; and finally I had my i3 window manager again.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to upgrade the system to 18.04 using tty1.

I ran into the same error message when I tried to upgrade my ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.  There was no error message during the upgrade process in the 14.04 system.  But the computer can't enter the graphic interface after the reboot required by the upgrade.  The desktop stuck at the fsck screen similar to the photo posted in the question.

I tried to install the most recent nvidia driver nvidia-430.  After the install, I stuck at the message "starting lsb: vpn client from palo alto netwrks globalprotect" right after the fsck result.  Reset xserver also doesn't help.

Eventually, I switched to tty1 and upgrade the system to 18.04.  I am able to enter the graphic interface right after the upgrade and a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by running Ubuntu once with the arguments `rw nomodeset` instead of `ro`. I assume the `ro` stands for "read-only" (which could hinder fsck if it tries to fix errors) and `rw` for "read-write". After that I could start my Ubuntu installation without problems with the normal arguments.
The problem occurred for me after an overload crash (my laptop got overloaded and hang, I pushed the power button for a few seconds), after that the problem occurred.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1288066)

Comment: @David How is my answer not answering the question?("I had the same problem and fixed it like follows" looks like a question to you?) I simply described how I fixed it when the problem occurred, thus providing a solution to the problem. Or isn't it wanted to describe how to fix the probelem here on AskUbuntu? Because no solution like mine has been posted here before I posted mine to contribute to the knowledge on this page.