# Updated laptop from 16.10 to 18.04 LTS, boot stuck at /dev/… clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks

Tags: boot, 18.04, updates, 16.10, fsck

Haven't touched this laptop in a while, so when I did, I updated it (from 16.something) to the most recent LTS (18.04) from the GUI prompt.

It is a dual-booting Windows 10/Ubuntu system.

I now have the purple background 5 dots ubuntu 'boot screen' for like 2 seconds, then it goes into a command line mode and get stuck at  /dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 291381/1324512 files, 3883511/5297920 blocks after selecting Ubuntu in GRUB.

I saw some other users fix by purging nvidia drivers, which my system does not have (no nvidia GPU, tried it anyway, just listed 0 installed, 0 removed etc.)

Also tried the [`nomodeset` update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850670/ubuntu-stuck-on-boot-wont-get-past-fsck), which also did not work, I just get stuck in Grub after pressing `ctrl-X` with the text all gone.

Saw some others suggest sudo apt update, to which I got these:

`Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease   Could not resolve 'au.archive.ubuntu.com' and similar 5 other lines, with the last one being cannot resolve 'dl.google.com'.`

Thinking it might my internet not connecting, I tried `ifconfig wlan 0`, to which I get `device not found`.

Does anyone know what I can do to get back into my system?

Comment: You have "18.04" and "16.10" so which is it?

Comment: It is the first reboot prompted after letting the system upgrade to 18.04, so I don't know if 18.04 has finished installation etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: I no longer have that laptop, but I don't think it would've been the solution anyway because it did not have an nvidia gpu, nor did I ever attempt to install nvidia drivers on it.