# /dev/nvme0n1p5 message; Ubuntu won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm new to Linux so I apologize if I get anything wrong.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and I can't boot it. Whenever I power on my laptop, shortly after a message appears saying "/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean followed by numbers of files and files that are blocked. I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows and this happened when restarting my laptop while plugged in to my monitor. I don't know what to do and the message doesn't disappear.

I hope someone can help, thanks

Comment: Have you tried the solution outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: I tried it but it kept saying incorrect login, I'm certain my password is correct, though I don't know what to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after trying numerous solutions this finally worked for me...

Ctrl+Alt+F2 which will lead you to a tty, login into tty using username and password, then, enter `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome gdm3`. There will be a big output but once it's done type `reboot` and you should be able to get Ubuntu back up again.

I got the answer from [them](https://askubuntu.com/users/384849/hd189733b) in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850670/ubuntu-stuck-on-boot-wont-get-past-fsck) (second answer). I skipped the rest of the steps and only entered that command and it worked.

I hope this works for you, good luck.

Comment: this was solved my issue.

Comment: I did this and it fixed the issue but my desktop got wonky. I just reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and everything went back to normal. So I recommend modifying the command to become `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome gdm3 ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution outlinked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)
["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Edit 1 :
If you are getting incorrect password when you try to purge nvidia drivers, and you are certain your password is correct, please make sure your keyboard layout hasn't changed. You can use this command to check the current layout : `setxkbmap -query`

Comment: I would try but I don't know where to input the command, it won't boot ubuntu so I can't access the terminal and I don't know what to put in for log in. Also if the layout changed it wouldn't affect me as my password is consistent of numbers and symbols

Comment: sorry mate. Maybe I got it all wrong. let me start over.

1. You are trying out a new display and when you boot up ubutntu, you are getting this message `/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean x files blocks *`
  --> It is normal for ubuntu to display that message and does not indicate any error.
2. You said you are getting an error 'incorrect login'. 
 --> If you cannot access terminal, how are you getting this error?

I think there is something wrong with your greeter or drivers needed to start x windows(or graphical interface). You can validate this by entering into tty, use alt+ctrl+f1-f6.

Comment: Thank you for help I really appreciate it. I'm afraid to say that I haven't been able to do much. Once I go into tty 2-6 I get a message prompting me to enter my login. Once I press F1 I get a list with [OK] and beside it either started it finished. I'm not sure what to do from here. I'm sorry if I'm betting anything wrong, hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: @Francisco, all good mate. Are you able to login to tty (f2-f6) with your password? I remember you saying you had trouble with password too.
If you can login with the password, can you check the logs using `journalctl _UID=<ur user id>`? You can get your userid by running the command `id`.

Comment: Yes, so I know my password but I don't know the login. I also don't know how to access the terminal other than the root terminal in recovery. When I go to tty 2-6 it prompts me for my login which I don't know, than it asks for my password which I do know. Perhaps you could tell me how to access the terminal while stuck on boot.

Comment: @Francisco, you can change your grub settings to login into single user mode as outlined here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub .
Once in Single User Mode, you can get the list of all the users in the system by checking `/etc/passwd`. Perhaps this will help you recollect the login.

Comment: so I managed to remember my login and successfully logging in. I tried several solutions from the page you linked above but none of them work. I was hoping you could help me out or suggest another fix. I appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: @Francisco, glad that you were able to recollect your login. Now that you have a login, can you view your logs using journalctl _UID=<ur user id>

Comment: Alright, I've done that. Says logs begin Wednesday at a certain time and below that, it reads "no entries"