# Cant login to tty on ubuntu 20.04, login incorrect and cant go to recovery

Tags: login, tty

Probably `/var` does not have free space. It had happened before that I needed to empty `/var`. That is why it prompts to tty when it starts. I can't log in normally.

It says after the prompt,

```
`/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean 203241/4063232 files 1974099/16250112 blocks`
```

It does not change. I restarted lots of times but always is the same numbers.

And, I cant cancel when I press `Ctrl + C` on the first screen. It immediately goes to that screen.

I put my username and password in any tty tty3 for example but it does not accept. Maybe I don't know my username. How can I see my username?

I can't even go to recovery mode on my HP laptop. I tried `f11` `f12` shift but it always goes to `Ctrl + C` and then clean the block writing :(

I used f11 to go to recovery mode but it goes that tty screen again. Please help.

**FIXED**

I did this and it seems to work: https://askubuntu.com/a/1279814/1566911 `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome gdm3` and then rebooted. now I am on my desktop. it showed `Ctrl + C` but it passed it quickly. Now I restarted 2 times and it seems no problem. Any suggestions? Why did I have this error? How can I go back to a normal desktop? I mean when I do `Ctrl + tab`, I can see only one chrome tab despite there being 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø i cant login. i need my username. And it is not about nvidia. I have /var full probably. but first i need to be able to login.

Comment: You have to enter your user name, not your name! If you cant still login even after entering your username then login as root. In the uername column enter `root` and in password column, enter your sudo password

Comment: You can boot to Recovery Mode ( from this answer: 
 https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/1158038)  and then you have bash, so you can chenge your username or password or clear /var.

Comment: I did this and it seems worked: https://askubuntu.com/a/1279814/1566911 `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome gdm3` and then rebooted. now i am on my desktop. it showed ctrl c but it passed it quickly. Now i restarted 2 times and it seems no problem. ANy suggestions? Why did i have this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/dev/nvme0n1p5 message; Ubuntu won't boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278718/dev-nvme0n1p5-message-ubuntu-wont-boot)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I founded :
Press Shift while PC is booting,
Go to Advanced Options,
Go to second option this will take to another option board,
Go down to the root option and click Enter,
Click enter again to maintenance,
You will see your username before @....
IF appears "root" that's means "root" is your username,
IF you want To reset password just type: passwd
And follow the steps...
AND exit... Then reboot
On tty write your username and password,
Then install Type "sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop"

After that will restart and take you to the graphical interface