# Ubuntu 22.04 not rebooting in AMD Radeon / AMD Ryzen 5 (MSI laptop)

Tags: amd-graphics

I am new to ubuntu. I am installing ubuntu 22.04 to my AMD Radeon / AMD Ryzen 5 (MSI laptop).

I am able to boot it from pendrive (safe mode where we get option to use ubuntu & install ubuntu).

But after completion of installation from pend drive, when it is restarting, it is not rebooting.Screen get blank with

Error : /dev/nvme0n1p5: clear, ...files,...blocks

Please suggest.

Comment: You had to not use the video card during install. So until the right video card driver is installed it will need to have the nomodeset parameter set in Grub.

Comment: If you google what is /dev/nvme0n1p5 you will find a few users had same problem Ubuntu not booting with message like yours. e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278718/dev-nvme0n1p5-message-ubuntu-wont-boot try and follow diagnosis and solutions on those questions. Ctrl+Alt+F2 to login to command-line. Check system and X(graphics server)logs :- `dmesg`; `ls -al /var/log`; `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log`. e.g. one solution maybe reinstall display manager then `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome gdm3`